# JavaFX Get node by clicking on node

Tags: java, javafx

I want to get the node one column to the left of the node I clicked on. How can I do this? I’ve been trying all sort of things but I can’t figure it out...

Thanks!

Comment: "Column" in what context?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say Im using a gridpane, so I need to get the node one column to the left on the grid